# ссылка с помощью razor

Tags: razor

Как записать в виде `data-value`? в данный момент `datavalue`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Позиционная", "Create", "Discount", new { Groups = Discount.GroupDiscountPosition } , new { @class = "dropdown-item", dataValue = Discount.GroupDiscountPosition })
```

Comment: в чем проблема? что за ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: @InDevX если написать `data-value`, то пишет "Неверное определение члена анонимного типа"

Comment: попробуйте `dataValue = ` заменить на `data val = `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data_value` должно [помочь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OxjOGl):

```
new {
    @class = "dropdown-item", 
    data_value = Discount.GroupDiscountPosition 
}
```

Или можно написать HTML явно:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Discount", new { Groups = Discount.GroupDiscountPosition })"
   class="dropdown-item"
   data-value="@Discount.GroupDiscountPosition">Позиционная</a>
```

Comment: `data_value` -  решение... спасибо большое